# MS Word Outline View - Format Wavy Line

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS Word, Outline View, the Wavy dotted line means that there is a [content inside](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/removing-a-zigzag-black-underline-in-outline-view/dedd11e5-0430-414e-a15a-e6a189f9075a) the given level. It is very handy feature, however, it is an eye sore. Is it possible to format it to less of an eye sore like changing to it more subtle grey dotted lines? I do not want to remove it, but just to format it. Thank you.

[image: zigzag wavy lines in word outline view]

Comment: It is not possible. Here is my page on outlining: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm

Comment: Too bad. However, @CharlesKenyon, the Outline view resource you have linked is truly incredible. I don't think, there is such wealth of information and knowledge about Outline view is available elsewhere. Please share with me any other tips/tricks you may have. Thank you.

Comment: These will lead you to many: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm https://addbalance.com/word/ http://word.mvps.org/ https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/BasicConceptsWord.htm

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKenyon. Are there good video tutorials out there? most that I found are pretty basic and rudimentary.

Comment: Those by Deborah Savadra and Laura Townsend are excellent and accurate. https://www.youtube.com/@DeborahSavadra https://www.youtube.com/@TownsendTek Also look at those from Kevin Startvert who is about a number of programs including Word https://www.youtube.com/@KevinStratvert. The pages that I originally gave you give links to many videos as well.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesKenyon for all the resources. Really appreciate it.